# Weird behaviour in TestNG with dependencies - no error raised

Tags: java, testing, error-handling, dependencies, testng

**Update:** I have also opened a *bug* in the [GitHub project](https://github.com/cbeust/testng) of TestNG [here](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/998).

---

I have made a *stupid* typographical mistake while defining one of my tests. I have accidentally written the annotation like so:

```
@Test(dependsOnMethods = {"method1, method2"}, alwaysRun = true)
```

Do you see the error? I sure didn't (since the real method names are also much longer), and it made me waste almost 2 hours because TestNG offers *no help* regarding this.

**Why it offers no help**:
As a result of this mistake, **no error** was raised, everything **compiled** fine, but when my suite was about the run it just skipped all the tests without any indication why:

```
__PLAN___
Total tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
```

There is also no place in the logs/xmls to show that something might be wrong.

Only after a long while I noticed that I meant to write:

```
@Test(dependsOnMethods = {"method1", "method2"}, alwaysRun = true)
```

Meaning that the test actually depends on 2 methods except one long one which obviously didn't exist.

I am now trying to add to our framework the option to alert the user of such mistake so it won't happen to any more people (we are a big company).

**Question:** Where could I find, in the TestNG's code perhaps, the code/documentation that will allow me to *grab* the event where TestNG *fails*, and act upon it? There *has to be* some place in there where TestNG checks the suite and decides to not run the test because of this problem, where is it?

Comment: Funny. This bug report seems to indicate the exact opposite situation: tests failing because existing methods cannot be found. https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/949 .

Comment: @Gimby Interesting, although I wouldn't say *exact opposite* since this situation is slightly less complicated (no inheritance issues etc...)

Comment: It might still be worth adding your case to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the error is ignored is because you've specified `alwaysRun=true` in your `@Test` declaration. From [`Test.java`](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/master/src/main/java/org/testng/annotations/Test.java#L105):

```
/**
 * If set to true, this test method will always be run even if it depends
 * on a method that failed.  This attribute will be ignored if this test
 * doesn't depend on any method or group.
 */
public boolean alwaysRun() default false;
```

Setting `alwaysRun=false` or removing it from your `@Test` declaration completely should give you the error you're expecting.

To answer your question of where TestNG checks for missing dependencies, it's in [`MethodHelper.java#findDependedUponMethods(ITestNGMethod , ITestNGMethod[])`](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/b1ac2e15f4a6698986746bf815bce67d0bb0a4dd/src/main/java/org/testng/internal/MethodHelper.java#L102). As you can see, having either `alwaysRun` or `ignoreMissingDependencies` set to `true` (they both default to `false`) will cause missing method dependencies to be silently ignored. I would avoid setting `alwaysRun=true` unless you have a specific reason to.